# Qual o code gml do MOVE FIXED no game maker?

Tags: gml

Gostaria de saber como é a função move fixed em gml (**linguagem do game maker**):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei alguns movimentos similares com os quais eu posso fazer algumas "gambiarras" para que os mesmos ajam da mesma forma que o **move fixed**, porém se o move fixed existe nas "actions" certamente que existe seu **código em gml**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem a solução na realidade é bem simples.

Quando fiz a pergunta eu estava querendo que houvesse uma randomização na direção em que o objeto fosse (esquerda/direira) depois de colidir com um outro, isso pode ser feito com o if.

```js
if (condiction01 == true){

  //ir para a direita com a velocidade 10
  move_towards_point(object.x+1,y,10);
  //valores positivos adicionados a x, o levam para a direita na horizontal

}else{

  //ir para a esquerda com a velocidade 10
  move_towards_point(object.x-1,y,10);
  //valores negativos adicionados a x, o levam para a esquerda na horizontal
  
}
```

Lembrando que mesmo o applies estando "selfie" é necessário essa indicação `object.x (+ ou -) 10` e não somente `x (+ ou -) 1` para ser relativo à sua posição.

O **y** é o contrário do convencional. Com `-` se vai para cima e com `+` se vai para baixo.

Onde a imagem começa? Imagino que tenha pensado que no canto superior esquerdo, pronto é por isso. O ponto **0, 0 (x , y)** fica no parte extrema superior esquerda, logo qualquer valor para baixo ou para o lado direito aumenta o seu valor.